# Unity3D - Google Play Games Sign In always fails

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement Google Play Games Services in my game, using GPGS plugin from GitHub. I have already made Google Play Console Pages and I have written script for signing in:

```
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using GooglePlayGames;

void Start()
{

    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("success");
        }
        else Debug.Log("failed");

    });
}
```

And... It doesn't work at all. Some people see the disapearing green popup in their apps, but I don't see anything. I really don't know what to do. I reinstalled all SDKs and read tens of forum themes without finding any solution.
Sorry for my English, I hope you can help me with my problem.

Comment: Aren't you missing the whole `PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config)` call?

Comment: @orhtej2 I added that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: The example code on [GitHub page](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) seems pretty self-explanatory to me, have you tried following that?

Comment: @orhtej2 Yes, and it doesn't work